# array formula and regexmatch won't follow through whole column

Tags: regex, google-sheets, array-formulas

I am having an issue with an Array Formula where my current formula is:

=ArrayFormula(if(REGEXMATCH(B2,to_text('Order Form 1'!A2:A))=true,"Approved",A2:A))

I am: 
1. matching the responseTimestamp (text) to the whole column of Orders received.
2. if it matches then show "Approved", 
3. else, it should populate the **Order not matched** into that cell.

It populates in the "Pending" column correctly if it (regex)matches "B2"; 
however, I have more data in that column and would like it to perform this formula over "B2:B".

When I do this it doesn't populate the correct answer.
Can anyone offer insights or a solution?

Here is a link to a copy of my workbook: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1utgP82XMkb8cOhKX2_taGqfluq6jHLNkOqUVJ31WHBM/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am trying to make a list of 'pending orders'.  This would be the remaining "Orders" from column A after subtracting column B & C from the list.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works

```
=ArrayFormula(if(REGEXMATCH(B2:B,TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 'Order Form 1'!A2:A)),"Approved",A2:A))
```

Or, if you just want to list the values from A that don't match in B, try

```
=filter(A2:A6, isna(match(A2:A6, B2:B6,0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=filter(A2:A6, isna(match(A2:A6, B2:B6,0)))
```

Thank you JPV, your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47605430/1595451) worked best for how my columns are arranged.